# htaccess issue - not rewriting url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know that this question has been asked a lot of times before but I need help. I have spent hours on this and I cant figure out what the heck is wrong in the following `htaccess` code.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule services/z/(.*)/ services.php?z=$1

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://rcunlocks.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I am trying to re-write the url

`https://rcunlocks.com/services.php?z=spus3`

to

`https://rcunlocks.com/services/spus3`

If anything is wrong with my htaccess file please tell me.

Your help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I guess you have to add `[NC,L]` after your rule because the last rule will rewrite everything back to the default structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
# check that the request url is neither a file nor a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^services/(.*) services.php?z=$1 [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues:

1. Redirect rule after rewrite can expose your internal URI `/services.php?z=spus3` to browsers
2. Option `MultiViews` can override this rewrite rule.

To fix both issue have it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^services/z/([^/]+)/?$ services.php?z=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I tried it, still no luck. I thought the L will stop it to move to the next rewrite rule.. am I correct?

Comment: What error are you getting when you enter `https://rcunlocks.com/services/spus3` URL in browser?

Comment: I got a multiple choices page - status 300

Comment: Well that means something outside these rules as none of my rules are returning status=300